# Set custom store marker on storeLocator.Store in Google

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drupal

I'm trying to set a custom marker for each of my stores.
Using the [Google storelocator](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-store-locator/reference.html), there is a [storeLocator.Store](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-store-locator/reference.html#storeLocator.Store) with a .setMarker option.

I tried a lot

```
var store = new storeLocator.Store(store_id, position, storeFeatureSet, storeProps);
var markerPin = new google.maps.Marker(
  icon: 'http://url-to-marker.png'
});
store.setMarker(markerPin);
```

I've been trying to find something on Google but there isn't much out there on the storelocator project.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out the [GIT repository of the store locator project](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-store-locator/). In this repository there are sample examples and the files that demonstrates the placement of the markers. If you dig into the examples directory and check out the file [places.js](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-store-locator/blob/gh-pages/examples/places.js). You can find the code of how places get populate with the markers. I am adding a small code snippet, for a detailed overview you can see the whole project.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28, 135),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var panelDiv = document.getElementById('panel');

  var data = new PlacesDataSource(map);

  var view = new storeLocator.View(map, data);

  var markerSize = new google.maps.Size(24, 24);
  view.createMarker = function(store) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: store.getLocation(),
      icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(store.getDetails().icon, null, null,
          null, markerSize)
    });
  };

  new storeLocator.Panel(panelDiv, {
    view: view
  });
});
```